# UIWebView/WKWebView crash on iOS11 (ran out of executable memory)

Tags: uiwebview, crash, webkit, ios11, wkwebview

Loading some web pages using UIWebView or WKWebView on iOS 11 causing crash with reason "Ran out of executable memory while allocating 128 bytes". The attached screenshot shows the full stack trace. It seems to be a problem with Webkit's Javascript engine. There was no such a problem on iOS 10 and earlier. So it's new on iOS 11. No problem on Simulator. Only on real device.

Here is an example URL which causes a crash:
https://wstream.video/mobi/iu94ezdbr6h4

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Here is the source code which I test on iPhone 6s running iOS 11:
https://github.com/msencenb/UIWebView-Example

Comment: Hi SZP, This code is not working.

Comment: Hi Paolpa, to run the example on iPhone you need to:
1. Set your developer certificate
2. In Build settings set Architectures to Standard
3. Add the following lines in your info.plist:
`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>`

Comment: To reproduce the crash in SimpleBrowserViewController.m -> viewDidLoad change the URL from google to https://wstream.video/mobi/iu94ezdbr6h4

If you need more URLs which cause crash let me know.

Comment: Hi SZP,
Yes, I asked this morning here because I have the same error that you. I also waiting that someone help us : )
I think that is related with WebAssembly

Comment: Following advise by Eskimo (Apple Dev Support) tried the same scenario but using the WKWebView. The problem persists with WKWebView  too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crypto mining script in your provided site causes this crash :(

If you truly want to mine a bitcoin in your webview, you can set the following environment variable to disable the buggy JIT in iOS 11:

```
setenv("JSC_useJIT", "false", 0);
```